# out of bounds error c#

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to read contents of a csv file into different variables in order to send to a web service.It has been working fine but suddenly today i got and exception.

index was outside the bounds of the array:

what Did I do wrong?

```
String sourceDir = @"\\198.0.0.4\e$\Globus\LIVE\bnk.run\URA.BP\WEBOUT\";
// Process the list of files found in the directory. 
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
foreach (string fileName2 in fileEntries)
{
    // read values
    StreamReader st = new StreamReader(fileName2);
    while (st.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        String report1 = st.ReadLine();
        String[] columns = report1.Split(','); //split columns 
        String prnout = columns[0];
        String tinout = columns[1];
        String amtout = columns[2];
        String valdate = columns[3];
        String paydate = columns[4];
        String status = columns[5];
        String branch = columns[6];
        String reference = columns[7];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, and get rid of all the commented out code. Use the preview to see what it will look like - make sure it's what *you'd* want to see if you were answering the question.

Comment: I bet you have a new input file that doesn't have 8 columns.

Comment: Where do you get your exception?

Comment: By the way, `Split(',')` is not an effective way to parse CSV.  You completely ignore the possibility of quote-encoded columns.

Comment: Just as a quick opimization thing change your while loop to `while((report1 = st.ReadLine()) != null)` then move the declration of report1 outside of the loop. That extra peek costs a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess without even seeing the .csv file, but my first one would be that you don't have 8 columns.

It would be easier if you could show the original .csv file, and tell us where the exception pops.

edit: If you think the data is alright, I'd suggest you debugging and see what the split call returns in Visual Studio. That might help

edit2: And since you're doing that processing in a loop, make sure each row has at least 8 columns.

Comment: @user1431339 Apparently you have a line that is not 10 columns wide.

Comment: this is a sample csv file 2130000138761,,80000,23/07/2012,23/07/2012,C,060147,TT1220510226,,

Comment: just noticed that it was working in the test environment but failing in live.after debugging the problem was with the remotes server side.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on bad data file.  If that is the only thing in the equation that has changed (aka you haven't made any code changes) then that's pretty much your only option.

If your data file isn't too long post it here and we can tell you for sure.

You can add something like below to check for invalid column lengths:

```
while (st.Peek() >= 0)
{
    String report1 = st.ReadLine();
    String[] columns = report1.Split(','); //split columns 

    if(columns.Length < 8)
    {
         //Log something useful, throw an exception, whatever.  
         //You have the option to quitely note that there was a problem and 
         //continue on processing the rest of the file if you want.
         continue;
    }

    //working with columns below
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for sanity's sake, I combined all the various notes written here.  This code is a bit cleaner and has some validation in it.

Try this:

```
string dir = @"\\198.0.0.4\e$\Globus\LIVE\bnk.run\URA.BP\WEBOUT\";
foreach (string fileName2 in Directory.GetFiles(dir)) {
    StreamReader st = new StreamReader(fileName2);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)  {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) {
            string[] columns = line.Split(',');
            if (columns.Length == 8) {
                string prnout = columns[0];
                string tinout = columns[1];
                string amtout = columns[2];
                string valdate = columns[3];
                string paydate = columns[4];
                string status = columns[5];
                string branch = columns[6];
                string reference = columns[7];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As some other users have commented, the CSV format also accepts text qualifiers, which usually means the double quote symbol (").  For example, a text qualified line may look like this:

```
user,"Hello!",123.23,"$123,123.12",and so on,
```

Writing CSV parsing code is a little more complicated when you have a fully formatted file like this.  Over the years I've been parsing improperly formatted CSV files, I've worked up a standard code script that passes virtually all unit tests, but it's a pain to explain.

```
/// <summary>
/// Read in a line of text, and use the Add() function to add these items to the current CSV structure
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s"></param>
public static bool TryParseLine(string s, char delimiter, char text_qualifier, out string[] array)
{
    bool success = true;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder work = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        char c = s[i];

        // If we are starting a new field, is this field text qualified?
        if ((c == text_qualifier) && (work.Length == 0)) {
            int p2;
            while (true) {
                p2 = s.IndexOf(text_qualifier, i + 1);

                // for some reason, this text qualifier is broken
                if (p2 < 0) {
                    work.Append(s.Substring(i + 1));
                    i = s.Length;
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }

                // Append this qualified string
                work.Append(s.Substring(i + 1, p2 - i - 1));
                i = p2;

                // If this is a double quote, keep going!
                if (((p2 + 1) < s.Length) && (s[p2 + 1] == text_qualifier)) {
                    work.Append(text_qualifier);
                    i++;

                    // otherwise, this is a single qualifier, we're done
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Does this start a new field?
        } else if (c == delimiter) {
            list.Add(work.ToString());
            work.Length = 0;

            // Test for special case: when the user has written a casual comma, space, and text qualifier, skip the space
            // Checks if the second parameter of the if statement will pass through successfully
            // e.g. "bob", "mary", "bill"
            if (i + 2 <= s.Length - 1) {
                if (s[i + 1].Equals(' ') && s[i + 2].Equals(text_qualifier)) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            work.Append(c);
        }
    }
    list.Add(work.ToString());

    // If we have nothing in the list, and it's possible that this might be a tab delimited list, try that before giving up
    if (list.Count == 1 && delimiter != DEFAULT_TAB_DELIMITER) {
        string[] tab_delimited_array = ParseLine(s, DEFAULT_TAB_DELIMITER, DEFAULT_QUALIFIER);
        if (tab_delimited_array.Length > list.Count) {
            array = tab_delimited_array;
            return success;
        }
    }

    // Return the array we parsed
    array = list.ToArray();
    return success;
}
```

You should note that, even as complicated as this algorithm is, it still is unable to parse CSV files where there are embedded newlines within a text qualified value, for example, this:

```
123,"Hi, I am a CSV File!
I am saying hello to you!
But I also have embedded newlines in my text.",2012-07-23
```

To solve those, I have a multiline parser that uses the Try() feature to add additional lines of text to verify that the main function worked correctly:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parse a line whose values may include newline symbols or CR/LF
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sr"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string[] ParseMultiLine(StreamReader sr, char delimiter, char text_qualifier)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] array = null;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {

        // Read in a line
        sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());

        // Does it parse?
        string s = sb.ToString();
        if (TryParseLine(s, delimiter, text_qualifier, out array)) {
            return array;
        }
    }

    // Fails to parse - return the best array we were able to get
    return array;
}
```

Comment: same thing..this is the csv file im reading 2130000138761,,80000,23/07/2012,23/07/2012,C,060147,TT1220510226,,

Comment: Which line in the code generates the out of bounds exception?

Comment: I've posted my open source CSV code here, please feel free to use it.  https://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many columns will be in csv file, you might need to test for length:

```
if (columns.Length == 8) {
     String prnout = columns[0];
     String tinout = columns[1];
     ...
}
```

I bet you just got an empty line (extra EOL at the end), and that's as simple as that

Comment: let mi try these ideas and get back to u.thanx